# What's the difference between color and texture?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, colors, computer-vision, textures

In the fields:

- image processing
- computer graphics
- image analysis
- computer vision

the concepts of texture and color are very used.

Can somebody give a short introduction to this concepts and specify the difference between
them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color is well, color ...

Texture is the statistics/description of how the colors change spatially.